# PHP Upload File leads to blank page

Tags: linux, php, nginx, php-fpm, upload

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html> 
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

When I upload I just eventually get a `The connection was reset` page

- I have nginx as a frontend and php-fpm as the backend
- php settings are set very high so no limits.

What should I try to debug this? I don't have anything in the error_log for PHP.

Comment: Have you checked your webserver or php-fpm error logs, there's a chance there's something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Review your error handling settings in php.ini and make sure that errors are not logged but displayed.

If that doesn't not help look into nging's error_log to see what if the reset comes from the server-process for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to upload a plain html file and ensure you can view that. I presume that is working so your webserver is there, you have the right dir, server etc. Second step would be to create a very simple PHP page showing the phpinfo. I know this is a silly question but did you name the file with a php extension?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Yes, html works. Yes, php works and yes it does.